# pip install from repo with proper caching and versioning

Tags: python, pip

How do I specify a requirement dependency from a private git repo, such that it will update if the sha of what it already installed doesn't match, but doesn't reinstall otherwise?

This is what I use now:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/myorg/mypkg.git@<full-sha-of-pinned-version>#egg=mypkgname
```

But if I `pip install` using different `<full-sha...>` values, it doesn't ever reinstall, saying "requirement already satisfied."

This seems different than when I do, say, `pip install realpkg==1.1.0` which will correctly reinstall when i change the version to `1.1.1`, say.

How do I get it to automatically upgrade if and only if the SHA changes (or a version specifier, but those don't seem to work either)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` compares package versions, not VCS URLs. Set version in `#egg=mypkgname-1.1.1`, increase it to `#egg=mypkgname-1.1.2` to make `pip` know the version changed.